# How can i determine the way in which app launched?

Tags: android, android-launcher, google-assistant-sdk

In my app I have to do some action if it is opened by saying **Open AppName** to Google Assistance. How can I find whether the app is opened with Google Assistance or not from the MianActivity?

Comment: You mean if it was open by click app icon or some different way?

Comment: @MaksimNovikov Yes

Comment: Try to call `getIntent()` in `MainActivity onCreate()` and check the action of the intent.

Comment: It is always android.intent.action.MAIN @MaksimNovikov

Comment: Even if you open with the assistance? Because i know this works fine for deeplinks.

Comment: Yeah it's working for deeplinking... But not for assistance @MaksimNovikov